# Cannot read from anonymous pipe

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, pipe

I began to study the anonymous pipe in windows and ran into a problem.

The program should create a child process that will handle the commands given ones to enter. But I can not read from the pipe until the child process works.

Here is the programm

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include "windows.h"
#include "cstdio"
#include "tchar.h"
#include "io.h"
#include "conio.h" 
#include "cstring"

static const int bufSize = 20;

int main() {
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION  pi;
    LPTSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(TEXT("Project2\\Release\\command_handler.exe"));
    HANDLE writePipe, readPipe, writePipeInput, readPipeInput;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    if(!CreatePipe(&readPipe, &writePipe, &sa, 0) || !CreatePipe(&readPipeInput, &writePipeInput, &sa, 0))
    {
        printf("ERROR: cannot create pipe\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdOutput = writePipe;
    si.hStdInput = readPipeInput;
    DWORD dwByteRead, dwByteWrite;
    if(!CreateProcess(0, szCmdline, 0, 0, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0, 0, &si, &pi)) {
        printf("ERROR: cannot create process\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(2);
    }
    CloseHandle(writePipe);
    CloseHandle(readPipeInput);
    printf("Procces ready!\n");

    TQueue <int> q;
    TQueue <int> tmp;
    char c;
    char s[bufSize];
    int value;
    for ( ; ; ) {
        int i;
        for(i = 0;i < bufSize && (s[i] = getchar()) != '\n';++i);
        WriteFile(writePipeInput,s,i + 1,&dwByteWrite,NULL);

        ReadFile(readPipe, &c, (int)1, &dwByteRead, NULL);
        printf("Get : '%c'\n",c);
        switch (c) {
            case '+':
                ReadFile(readPipe, &value, sizeof(int), &dwByteRead, NULL);
                printf("%d\n",value);
                q.push(value);
                printf("OK\n");
                break;
            case '-':
                if (!q.empty()) {
                    q.pop();
                }
                printf("OK\n");
                break;
            case 'f':
                if (!q.empty()) {
                    printf("%d\nOK\n",q.firstEl());
                } else {
                    printf("Queue is empty\nOK\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'p':
                if (q.empty()) {
                    printf("empty");
                }
                while (!q.empty()) {
                    tmp.push(q.firstEl());
                    printf("%d ",q.firstEl());
                    q.pop();
                }
                printf("\nOK\n");
                while (!tmp.empty()) {
                    q.push(tmp.firstEl());
                    tmp.pop();
                }
                break;
            case 'e':
                printf("%s\nOK\n",q.empty()?"yes!":"no");
                break;
            case 'q':
                break;
            case '?':
                printf("ERROR: undefined command\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Fatal error: wrong symbol from hadeler '%c'\n",c);
                //system("pause");
                //exit(3);
        }
        if (c == 'q') break;
    }
    CloseHandle(readPipe);
    CloseHandle(writePipeInput);
    printf("Exited normaly\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

And this is handler

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static const int sz = 10;

char read_cmd(char *s) {
    char c = getchar();
    int i;
    for (i = 0;(i < sz) && (c != ' ') && (c != '\n');i++) {
        s[i] = c;
        c = getchar();
//      printf("%c",s[i]);
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return c;
}

char correct(char res) {
    if (res != '\n') {
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    char s[sz + 1];
    char c, res;
    int val = 0;
    for ( ; ; ) {
        res = read_cmd(s);
        if (strcmp(s,"add") == 0) {
            val = 0;
            while ((c = getchar()) >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                val = val * 10 + c - '0';
            }
            res = c;
            c = '+';
        }else if (strcmp(s,"pop") == 0) {
            c = '-';
        }else if (strcmp(s,"first") == 0) {
            c = 'f';
        }else if (strcmp(s,"print") == 0) {
            c = 'p';
        }else if (strcmp(s,"empty") == 0) {
            c = 'e';
        }else if (strcmp(s,"help") == 0) {
            c = 'h';
        }else if (strcmp(s,"quit") == 0) {
            c = 'q';
        }else {
            c = '?';
        }
        if (!correct(res)) c = '?';
        printf("%c",c);
        if (c == 'q') break;
        if (c == '+') printf("%d",val);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So if I run it and immediately type "quit" it works, otherwise it stop when trying get result from output pipe.

Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but there are already functions to [read lines](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) in the standard C library. And even [better functions (IMO)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in the standard C++ library (though you're not really writing a C++ program).

Comment: As for your problem, run your programs in a debugger, and step through line by line to see where the problem is.

Comment: The handler works fine, but how can I check why ReadFile() continues to wait for data entry I don't know.

Comment: You are not setting up the pipes correctly, and you are not providing a pipe for stderr.  Read the MSDN documentation: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)

Comment: Also, use `PeekNamedPipe()` to detect when the pipe has data and how much can be read from it.  Don't use `ReadFile()` blindly.

Comment: These are examples where a single message is sent and the process ends (I got it). I want to after my message handling child process started processing the following message, and if you do not complete the process of reading the response does not occur. So I'm asking how to fight it.

Comment: Find out what the fifth parameter (`lpOverlapped`) to [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx) is used for and you know how to implement your application. Hint: [Synchronous and Asynchronous I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the program again and it worked. Honestly, I do not know that there was not correct. Here is a working version:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE

#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

#define BUFSIZE 256

template <class T> class TQueue {
private:
    class TQueEl {
    public:
        T value;
        TQueEl *next, *prev;
    };
    TQueEl *first, *last;
    int size;
public:
    int& operator = (TQueue <T>& b){
        while (!empty ()) {
            pop ();
        }
        while (!b.empty ()) {
            push(b.firstEl ());
            b.pop ();
        }
    }
    TQueue () {
        size = 0;
        first = last = nullptr;
    }
    void push (T val) {
        if (size == 0) {
            first = last = new TQueEl;
            first -> next = first -> prev = nullptr;
            first -> value = val;
        } else {
            last -> next = new TQueEl;
            last -> next -> prev = last;
            last = last -> next;
            last -> next = nullptr;
            last -> value = val;
        }
        size++;
    }
    T firstEl () {
        return first -> value;
    }
    void pop () {
        TQueEl *tmp=first;
        if (size == 1) {
            first = last = nullptr;
        } 
        else if ( empty() ) {
            // error("pop of empty queue");
        }
        else {
            first = first -> next;
            first -> prev = nullptr;
        }
        size--;
        delete tmp;
    }
    bool empty () {
        return !size;
    }
    ~TQueue () {
        TQueEl *tmp;
        while (first != nullptr) {
            tmp = first;
            first = first -> next;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }
};

DWORD WINAPI rerout(LPVOID params) {
    DWORD dwByteWrite, dwByteRead;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    HANDLE hParentStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE childInput = (HANDLE) params;
    for ( ; ; ) {
        ReadFile(hParentStdIn, buffer, BUFSIZE, &dwByteRead, NULL);
        WriteFile(childInput, buffer, dwByteRead, &dwByteWrite, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() { 
    HANDLE childInputRd = NULL;
    HANDLE childInputWr = NULL;
    HANDLE childOutputRd = NULL;
    HANDLE childOutputWr = NULL;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa; 

    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

    if ( ! CreatePipe(&childOutputRd, &childOutputWr, &sa, 0) ) {
        printf("Fatal error: cannot create child output pipe\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (! CreatePipe(&childInputRd, &childInputWr, &sa, 0)) {
        printf("Fatal error: cannot create child input pipe\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(2);
    }
    TCHAR szCmdline[]=TEXT("Project2\\Release\\command_handler.exe");
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi; 
    STARTUPINFO si;

    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
    si.hStdError = childOutputWr;
    si.hStdOutput = childOutputWr;
    si.hStdInput = childInputRd;
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    if ( !CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) ) {
        printf("Fatal error: cannot create child process\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(3);
    }
    else {
        CloseHandle(childInputRd);
        CloseHandle(childOutputWr);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }

    DWORD reroutThreadID;
    HANDLE inputRerouting = CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)rerout,(LPVOID) childInputWr,0 , &reroutThreadID);
    if (inputRerouting == NULL) {
        printf("Fatal error: cannot create thread\n");
        system("pause");
        exit (4);
    }

    TQueue <int> q;
    TQueue <int> tmp; 
    DWORD dwRead; 
    CHAR c;
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    for (;;) {
        ReadFile( childOutputRd, &c, sizeof(char), &dwRead, NULL);
        switch (c) {
            case '+':
                int value;
                ReadFile( childOutputRd, &value, sizeof(int), &dwRead, NULL);
                q.push(value);
                printf("OK\n");
                break;
            case '-':
                if (!q.empty()) {
                    q.pop();
                    printf("OK\n");
                }
                else {
                    printf("Queue is empty!\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'f':
                if (!q.empty()) {
                    printf("%d\n",q.firstEl());
                } else {
                    printf("Queue is empty!\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'p':
                printf("\n>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n\n");
                if (q.empty()) {
                    printf("empty");
                }
                while (!q.empty()) {
                    tmp.push(q.firstEl());
                    printf("%d ",q.firstEl());
                    q.pop();
                }
                while (!tmp.empty()) {
                    q.push(tmp.firstEl());
                    tmp.pop();
                }
                printf("\n\n<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n\nOK\n");
                break;
            case 'e':
                printf("%s\n",q.empty()?"YES":"NO");
                break;
            case 'q':
                break;
            case '?':
                printf("ERROR: undefined command\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Fatal error: wrong symbol from hadeler '%c'\n",c);
                system("pause");
                exit(5);
        }
        if (c == 'q') break;
    }
    CloseHandle(inputRerouting);
    CloseHandle(childInputWr);
    CloseHandle(childOutputRd);
    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

And the handler:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 5 

HANDLE hStdin, hStdout;
DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 

void readCmd(char* s) {
    ReadFile(hStdin, s, 1, &dwRead, NULL);
    int i;
    for (i = 0;(i < BUFSIZE) && (s[i] != ' ') && (s[i] != '\n') && (s[i] != '\r');i++) {
        ReadFile(hStdin, s + i + 1, 1, &dwRead, NULL);
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
}

bool correct() {
    char c;
    ReadFile(hStdin, &c, sizeof(char), &dwRead, NULL);
    if (c != '\n') {
        while (c != '\n') ReadFile(hStdin, &c, sizeof(char), &dwRead, NULL);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() { 
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
    if ( (hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) || (hStdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ) {
        ExitProcess(1); 
    } 
    int val;
    char s[BUFSIZE + 1];
    char c,digit;
    for (;;) { 
        readCmd(s);
        if (strcmp(s,"add") == 0) {
            val = 0;
            ReadFile(hStdin, &digit, 1, &dwRead, NULL);
            if (digit == '\n') {
                c = '?';
                WriteFile(hStdout,&c,sizeof(char),&dwRead,NULL);
                continue;
            }
            else if (digit < '0' || digit > '9') {
                c = '?';
            }
            else {
                c = '+';
            }
            while (digit >= '0' && digit <= '9') {
                val = val * 10 + digit - '0';
                ReadFile(hStdin, &digit, 1, &dwRead, NULL);
            }
        }else if (strcmp(s,"pop") == 0) {
            c = '-';
        }else if (strcmp(s,"first") == 0) {
            c = 'f';
        }else if (strcmp(s,"print") == 0) {
            c = 'p';
        }else if (strcmp(s,"empty") == 0) {
            c = 'e';
        }else if (strcmp(s,"help") == 0) {
            c = 'h';
        }else if (strcmp(s,"quit") == 0) {
            c = 'q';
        }else {
            c = '?';
        }
        if (!correct()) c = '?';
        WriteFile(hStdout, &c, 1, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (c == 'q') break;
        if (c == '+') WriteFile(hStdout, &val, sizeof(int), &dwRead, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you all for your help!